# How to set up pfSense/OPNSense on virtual host?

Tags: virtualization, routing, kvm-virtualization, pfsense

I'm a little confused as how to to host a *Sense box as a VM and have it provide routing for the host.

```
Internet -> Modem/Router (bridge mode) -> en1 on Dell r710 -> OPNSense in a VM

Then also:
OPNSense in a VM -> en2 -> 12-port switch
```

Like what do I set the network interfaces for on the VM, and how do I define OPNSense to have 10.0.2.1 as its IP and have it be the main router (dhcp, etc) so that OPNSense can provide routing for any device I connect (via a switch I have), and also the host the VM runs on?

My VM's are running on KVM with Wok/Kimchi on Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the question is a little too imprecise and i don't have the reputation to ask further questions.
A few days ago I set up OPNSense in a virtual environment, so hopefully I can leave a few hints here.
I don't claim that this is a good solution but it works for me. 
In this scenario i have a dedicated server and a /29 public IP subnet.
All traffic from other VM's is routed through the OPNSense-VM. 
The traffic of the host machine cannot be sent through the virtual machine.

For administration of the networks and virtual machines i use [WebvirtCloud](https://github.com/retspen/webvirtcloud)
but it's also possible to do everything manually.

1. Create virtual network interfaces for each of your public IPs.

   ```
   /etc/network/interfaces

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
           address 103.x.x.104      #Dedicated server IP address
           netmask 255.255.255.255
           gateway 103.x.x.65
           pointopoint 103.x.x.65   #IP of the switch in the data center

   auto eth0:0
   iface eth0:0 inet static
   address 103.xx.77.136             #First IP from the public subnet
   netmask 255.255.255.255

   auto eth0:1
   iface eth0:1 inet static
   address 103.xx.77.137
   netmask 255.255.255.255
   ```

   [...]
2. Use libvirt to create the networks as described [here](https://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html/sect-net-create.html): 
   (or use WebvirtCloud) 
   You need atleast two bridges, one for LAN the other one for WAN.

At this point you should have one network called LAN (Device: virbr1)(Network: 192.168.100.0/24)
and another one called WAN (Device: virbr0) (Network: 192.168.77.0/24)

3. Create your OPNSense Machine configuration
   This is the important part:

> ```
> <interface type='network'>
>       <mac address='00:52:66:d7:7e:65'/>
>       <source network='WAN' bridge='virbr0'/>
>       <target dev='vnet0'/>
>       <model type='virtio'/>
>       <alias name='net0'/>
>       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
>     </interface>
>     <interface type='network'>
>       <mac address='00:c0:41:50:f9:0b'/>
>       <source network='lan' bridge='virbr1'/>
>       <target dev='vnet1'/>
>       <model type='virtio'/>
>       <alias name='net1'/>
>       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
>     </interface>
>     <interface type='network'>
>       <mac address='00:98:c3:b1:b6:b8'/>
>       <source network='lan' bridge='virbr1'/>
>       <target dev='vnet2'/>
>       <model type='virtio'/>
>       <alias name='net2'/>
>       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
>     </interface>
> ```

4. Start OPNSense, assign interfaces according to your machine configuration and set interface IP addresses via the terminal.
   I have selected 192.168.77.2 for my OPNSense WAN IP address.
   The WAN upstream gateway is set to 192.168.77.1.

I also created seperate LAN's for each of my public IP's in OPNSense.

```
LAN136 IP-Address: 192.168.100.136/24 
LAN137 IP-Address: 192.168.100.137/32
No upstream Gateways.
```

[...]

5. NAT POST- and PREROUTING rules on hostmachine

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.77.2 -j SNAT --to-source 103.x.x.104
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.77.136 -j SNAT --to-source 103.xx.77.136
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.77.137 -j SNAT --to-source 103.xx.77.137
>
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10:65530 -d 103.xx.77.136 -j DNAT --to 192.168.77.136
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 10:65530 -d 103.xx.77.136 -j DNAT --to 192.168.77.136
>
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10:65530 -d 103.xx.77.137 -j DNAT --to 192.168.77.137
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 10:65530 -d 103.xx.77.137 -j DNAT --to 192.168.77.137
> ```

After this step you should be able to open OPNSense from your web browser.
In order to do that you need a virtual machine that is already part of the LAN. 
I recommend using a live CD like grml or Ubuntu.
In this case, OPNSense can be reached via http://192.168.100.136

6. OPNSense (web browser) - Create virtual IPs on WAN interface

> ```
> Virtual IP-address    Interface           TYPE
> 192.168.77.136/32         WAN          IP Alias
> 192.168.77.137/32         WAN          IP Alias
> ```

[...]

7. NAT Rules in OPNSense (web browser)
   Create your port forwarding and outgoing rules

example port forwarding:

> ```
> Interface Proto   S-address S-port    D-address       D-port       NAT-Ip         Nat-Port
> WAN           TCP     *           *       192.168.77.137  80 (HTTP)   192.168.100.101 80 (HTTP)
> ```

example outgoing rules:

mode must be set to manual

> ```
> Interface     Source                S-port    Dest.    D-port       NAT-IP        Port   static?
> WAN               192.168.100.100/32      *        *        *         192.168.77.136  *       no
> ```

Make sure all your public IP's have outgoing rules and a unique NAT IP.

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap... This is complex! I've been looking to replace my dedicated miniPC-run OPNsense setup with a VM on my TrueNAS (Scale now, but I've run Core for many years) server, and I was just wondering... is there a simpler way to get it all working? All I'd want is it to literally run my network and have the VM be able to communicate via WAN and LAN (inside and outside the VM of course...). I'm well aware that if I reboot my TrueNAS server (it's primarily my Plex Media Server) that my internet connection will go down etc. I'm also well aware that it isn't ideal in most situations to do this, but I want to try it out. I'm all about smaller footprints, and if I can get rid of a computer running on my network and in my room that'd be awesome.

Now as for what I've been able to do so far? I've only been able to get my OPNsense VM to see a WAN connection, as well as I'm able to get into its webUI... sometimes...

Any help would be appreciated if anyone sees this in 2023... lol. There's no rush, but I kinda want to do it cuz it's interesting.

Thanks,
Shiggitay